# Laravel - Pagination

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5

I have a table with pagination and when i click in next page icon the view is loaded.

**Controller Function:**

```
 public function index() { 
    $items = Items::where('active', '=', 1)->paginate(5); 
    return view('app/items.index', array('items' => $items)); 
  }
```

**jQuery:**

```
function pagination() { 
   $(document).on("click", ".pagination a", function(e) { 
          e.preventDefault(); 
       /* var page = $(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1]; 
        alert($(this).attr('href')); 
        $.ajax({ url: $(this).attr('href'), }) .done(function(data) { 
           //console.log(data); 
           $('#listSearchItems').html(data); 
         }); */
      }); 
   }
```

There is a way to not return view in ajax calls?
Thank's

Comment: What do you mean by not return view?

Comment: if(request()->ajax()){
  //ajax
}
else
{
 //non-ajax
}

Comment: i don't want that load the view to $('#listSearchItems') but just update my table data...